# Question about Series of Functions

Tags: real-analysis

May you help me with this problem?

Thank you so much!

How can I prove that series number **1** is equal to series number **2**?

I noticed that series number **1** is equal to $\frac{1}{k^4}$ when $k$ is even and to $\frac{2}{k^4}$ when $k$ is odd. But, no more than that...

Here is the series number **1**

$$\large{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos\left(\frac{k\pi}{2}\right)}{k^4}}$$

and here is the series number **2**

$$\large{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k^4}+\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{(2k)^4}\right)}$$

Comment: You might want to check "I noticed that series number **1** is equal to $\frac{1}{k^4}$ when $k$ is even and to $\frac{2}{k^4}$ when $k$ is odd"

Comment: @Henry Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $ \cos(j\pi/2)$ is zero if $j$ is odd and $(-1)^k$ if $j$ is even $j=2k$. The zero terms have been removed & then the sum has been reordered to give the expression stated in your question.

Comment: +1. Also worth noting that $\displaystyle\sum \frac1{k^4}$ and similar series are absolutely convergent, thus allowing reordering